# What are these hidden chars (e.g. "⇧") in typefaces exactly?

Tags: html, unicode, fonts, typeface

They are quite common and often used in e-mail footers like ☎ ✉, but when I wondered what these characters exactly are I couldn't find anything useful.

They don't seem to be part of the font that is the current context.
I know you can write them as HTML entities `&#9814;` ♖ and I suspect it's unicode(?).

So what are they exactly? 
And can/should you use these symbols on the web instead of images for example?
Do all browsers support them?

Answer (score 3):

“☎” is U+260E [BLACK TELEPHONE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/260e/index.htm), and “✉” is U+2709 [ENVELOPE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2709/index.htm). They are originally icon-like characters, often used to denote telephone number and some kind of message, typically e-mail. They do not have exact definitions of meanings; the Unicode Standard defines just various formal properties for them.

They are not “hidden characters in typefaces”. A typeface is a collection of glyphs, and if a typeface lacks a glyph for a character, the character is simply absent from the typeface, not “hidden”.

You can write them, like any Unicode characters, using numeric character references. Yes, they are Unicode, like almost any character is.

Whether you should use them on web pages instead of images is primarily a matter of opinion, with different pros and cons involved.

They are supported by practically all browsers, *if* a suitable font is used. Apart from special cases like speech-based browsers, this is really a font issue more than anything else. You cannot expect all *computers* to have a font containing them,

Answer (score 1):

That's the [Miscellaneous Symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf) code-point block.

Unicode groups code-points into [blocks](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#block) and you can get a sense of how they're grouped by looking at the [chart directory](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) which includes

> Miscellaneous Symbols (U+26xx)
>
> - Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows (U+2Bxx)
> - Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs (U+1F3xx)

under the "Symbols and Punctuation" category.

---

> I know you can write them as HTML entities `&#9814;` ♖ and I suspect it's unicode(?).

HTML characters are Unicode code-points.  `&#9814;` is an HTML ["numeric character reference"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/syntax.html#character-references) and the `9814` specifies the code-point.

> The ampersand must be followed by a "#" (U+0023) character, followed by one or more digits in the range ASCII digits, representing a base-ten integer that corresponds to a Unicode code point that is allowed according to the definition below. The digits must then be followed by a ";" (U+003B) character.

Comment: Do you know anything about their support in browsers?

Comment: @Jonathan, their support in browsers depends upon the font used to render the text containing them.  I believe Arial has glyphs for every code-point in that code-page and is available in all mainstream browsers.

Comment: Unicode does not have code pages, as should be obvious from the Unicode glossary entry linked to.

Comment: Arial does not contain the two characters mentioned.

Comment: Mike is confusing bog standard Arial with the aptly named [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS), at the time of appearance a fair attempt of creating a catch-all fallback font. But the set of Unicode characters is expanding with every new version; while you can find TELEPHONE in it, GRINNING CAT FACE WITH SMILING EYES () is not.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I misused the term "code-page" where I should have used the term "block".  Edited.